# Error when running dynamic web project in eclipse

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am new to servlets and jsp in eclipse.. I made a simple servlet/jsp application, but when i ran it on my tomcat server in eclipse i got the following errors:

> jun 21, 2013 1:07:01 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener
>   init INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows
>   optimal performance in production environments was not found on the
>   java.library.path: C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program
>   Files/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program
>   Files/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Android;C:\cygwin\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin;C:\Users\Mads\Downloads\programmer\eclipse\eclipse;;.
>   jun 21, 2013 1:07:02 AM
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin WARNING:
>   [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting
>   property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:DynamicWebProject1'
>   did not find a matching property. jun 21, 2013 1:07:03 AM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO: Initializing
>   ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"] jun 21, 2013 1:07:03 AM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO: Initializing
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"] jun 21, 2013 1:07:03 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load INFO: Initialization
>   processed in 4696 ms jun 21, 2013 1:07:04 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal INFO: Starting
>   service Catalina jun 21, 2013 1:07:04 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal INFO: Starting
>   Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.41 jun 21, 2013 1:07:06 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom INFO:
>   Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using
>   [SHA1PRNG] took [240] milliseconds. jun 21, 2013 1:07:06 AM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFO: Starting
>   ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"] jun 21, 2013 1:07:06 AM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFO: Starting
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"] jun 21, 2013 1:07:06 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start INFO: Server startup in
>   3101 ms jun 21, 2013 1:07:06 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await SEVERE:
>   StandardServer.await: create[localhost:8005]:  java.net.BindException:
>   Address already in use: JVM_Bind  at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.net.ServerSocket.(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:427)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:766)    at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:712)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)
>
> jun 21, 2013 1:07:06 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause INFO:
>   Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"] jun 21, 2013 1:07:08 AM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler
>   ["ajp-bio-8009"] jun 21, 2013 1:07:09 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal INFO: Stopping
>   service Catalina jun 21, 2013 1:07:09 AM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler
>   ["http-bio-8080"] jun 21, 2013 1:07:10 AM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler
>   ["ajp-bio-8009"] jun 21, 2013 1:07:11 AM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy INFO: Destroying
>   ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"] jun 21, 2013 1:07:11 AM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy INFO: Destroying
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]

I can't figure out what's wrong. can anyone help me out here?

Comment: `INFO` are not errors, they are INFO

Comment: From the logs, the key is `Address already in use: JVM_Bind`. A tomcat server is already running, shut that down and then try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> create[localhost:8005]: java.net.BindException: Address already in
>   use: JVM_Bind at

It indicates that you already have a server listening in the port **8005**.

Check if you already have started web project and didn't stop it or there is another server using this port.

**8005** is the port used by the Tomcat admin, to change this port double click the server inside the `Servers View`, and change it under the `Ports` section.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that port **8005** is already in use..

Use [TCP View](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) (if really on Windows 7) to figure out which process is binding it.